# What may be this line's equation?

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, graphing-functions

I have a line like this:

[image]

The values are not perfect (means the values can be changed), but all are non-negative values. I like to know the equation's equation or function.

I have tried-

$y=\ln(x)$

$y=e^x$

$y=\sin(x)$

$y=\tan(x)$

But nothing is matching this equation so much. I am thinking it may be some kind of transformations of $y=1/e^x$, but I am not sure about it.

So, can anyone please help me to find the equation formula, please?

Thanks in advance for helping :)

Comment: May be, you could add the data points. It will make analysis easier.

Comment: Point values are not important I think. I don't need a perfect equation, I just need the type of equation.

Comment: And points should stay on first co-ordinate, so x,y all values should be positive or 0

Comment: If x<0, y=0 and if Y<0, x=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it like this-

$$f(x) = ab^{x}$$

Where:
$$ a > 0 $$
$$ 0< b < 1 $$
$$ x\ge 0 , x \in Z $$

More can be found in **[here](https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Algebra1/FunctionGraphs/FNGTypeExponential.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

Try $$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac1{x^k} & x > 0 \\ 0 & x\le0 \end{cases}$$

where $k > 0$ or

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-kx} & x \ge 0 \\ 0 & x <0 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the form $$y=\frac1{x+c}-\frac1{x_0+c},$$ we find $$c=\frac12\left(\sqrt{x_0^2+\frac{4x_0}{y_0}}-x_0\right),$$
where $x_0$ and $y_0$ are the $x$ and $y$ intercepts respectively.

You can view this equation modelling your line [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/myp51sbxsk).